# capture ISBN number with android camera

Tags: android, android-intent, isbn

My application purpose just simply captures a ISBN number then converts ISBN to a string. I know about the zxing project, however after skimming their code and research, I couldn't find the way to use their code without using Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ISBN");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

How can I avoid this step to make my application standalone from Barcode Scanner application ?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/ provides a library. You can put it in your application, therefore eliminate this dependency. You code would be much more complicated of course.

Comment: I thought they support some ways to completely integrate Barcode Application into another application without installing

Comment: Why is it not acceptable for your application to use zxing via a Intent? Notice that you can pass various extra arguments along with the intent to change various behaviour, such as adding a prompt message. See http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/Intents.java (javadoc at http://zxing.org/w/docs/javadoc/com/google/zxing/client/android/Intents.Scan.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seem to be the dependency on Zxing Barcode Scanner being present on users devices. As Gene mentions in his comment Zxing provides a "IntentIntegrator" library for this use case. It's a small Java library that you bundle with your app and handles the case where Zxing is not installed on the phone for you, amongst other things.

It is described at http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent. See also http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fandroid-integration%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fzxing%2Fintegration%2Fandroid for details (source for this library).